# React: Checkbox triggers rendering only once

Tags: reactjs

This might be a very newbie thing, but I can't understand why the component doesn't re-render after a checkbox is triggered. It happens only the first time. So I have the following component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    let array = [child];

    if (this.state.checked) {
      child = <Child />
    } else {
      child = null
    }

    onClick = e => {
      this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
          />
          <span>Checkbox</span>
        </label>
        {array}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 export default Parent;
```

Basically, the expected behavior is:

1. The component renders, the initial state of `checked` is `false`, hence the `<Child />` component is not shown.
2. The checkbox is triggered, the `<Child />` component in the `array`, since the state is true.
3. The component renders, showing the `<Child />`.
4. The checkbox is triggered setting the state to false,
5. The component renders NOT showing the `<Child />`, since it should be `null`.

With my code, steps 1, 2, 3 happen as expected, but when I uncheck the checkbox, the component does not render, and the `<Child />` is still there.

What is conceptually wrong in this code, and how to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, move `onClick` handler out out `render`
2nd, I am not sure where you are receiving `child` in `let array = [child];`

Instead of setting non-existent `child` variable to a component, just display it when `this.state.checked` is true in `render`

```
{this.state.checked ? <Child /> : null}
```

Here is the working sample.
[image: Edit 4zm064z0nx]

Full source code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Child = () => <div>I am a Child component</div>;

class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    checked: false
  };

  onClick = e => {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
          />
          <span>Checkbox</span>
        </label>
        {this.state.checked ? <Child /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have added your code, but, even though your example works perfectly, my component still renders it once, and then the Child stays there when I uncheck the checkbox :/ Seems the issue is in something else. Is is possible to achieve the same with component lifecycle methods?

Comment: If the child is not going away, that means the `this.state.checked` is not being updated. So I say check whether `onClick` method handler is properly updating `this.state.checked` value.

Comment: I have a componentDidMount inside of the child, I suspect that is the issue. So it mounts and doesn't go away.

Comment: In that method, if you don't change a state, render probably would not be fired as you suspected.

Comment: No, I don't do anything there... could you please edit your answer taking into acount that the Child has componentDidMount?

Comment: @Ruham Ah, I misunderstood the question. `componentDidMount` "inside Child component" should not affect whether it's visible or not unless you are passing `this.state.checked` to the child component.